# Discussing the convergence of $\int_I\frac{x+2}{\sqrt x\left(x^2+x+1\right)^4}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

> Let $$f(x) = \frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x}\left(x^2 + x + 1\right)^4}$$ Discuss the convergence of $\displaystyle\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ and $\displaystyle\int_1^{+\infty}f(x)\,\mathrm dx$.

I encountered this problem in a test about improper integrals, so I expect that there is a solution which does not require evaluating the integral.

**My attempt**
Substitute $\sqrt{x} = t$ so that the bounds remain the same and the integral becomes:
$$\int\frac{2t^2 + 4}{\left(t^4 + t^2 + 1\right)^4}\mathrm dt$$

Since $\displaystyle\lim_{t \to 0} f(t) = 4$ and $f(t)$ is decreasing, the function is bounded on $(0, 1]$ and the integral converges.

What about the other one? I was not able to conclude anything useful, other than that it goes to $0$ towards $+\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- At $x=0$ we have

$$f(x)\sim_0\frac{2}{\sqrt x}$$
and the integral
$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}$$
is convergent hence the integral
$$\int_0^1f(x)dx$$
is also convergent.

- At $\infty$ we have

$$f(x)\sim_\infty\frac1{x^7\sqrt x}$$
and since 
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^7\sqrt x}$$
is convergent then
$$\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$$
is also convergent.

Comment: Oh, how did you find the asymptotic $\frac1{x^7\sqrt{x}}$?

Comment: At $\infty$ the numerator is equivalent to $x$ and the denumerator is equivalent to $x^8\sqrt x$.

Comment: Right, now I see. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.